# Why will Doctrine ORM will not create SQL query for my 1-to-many model?

Tags: sql, orm, codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-query

I know this has to have an easy answer, but I cannot figure it out.  After tears, I am hoping someone here can help.

Here is my YML model:

```
Identity:
  columns:
    id:
      type:           integer(10)
      primary:        true
      autoincrement:  true
    username:
      type:           string(255)

Profile:
  columns:
    id:
      type:           integer(10)
      primary:        true
      autoincrement:  true
    identity_id:
      type:           integer(10)
    profiletype_id:
      type:           integer(10)
    name:
      type:           string(255)
  relations:
    Identity:
      local:          identity_id
      foreign:        id
      class:          Identity
      foreignAlias:   Profiles
    Profiletype:
      local:          profiletype_id
      foreign:        id
      class:          Profiletype
      foreignAlias:   Profiles

Profiletype:
  columns:
    id:
      type:           integer(10)
      primary:        true
      autoincrement:  true
    type:
      type:           string(255)
```

As you can see, 3 linked tables are generated:

Identity
- can have multiple Profiles

Profile
- has one Identity
- has one Profiletype

Profiletype
- can have multiple Profiles

Now, In my code, I can perform queries on the generated models for Identity and Profiletype.

For example:

```
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
          ->select('i.*')
          ->from('Identity i');
        echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

will work and produce:

```
SELECT i.id AS i__id, i.username AS i__username FROM identity i
```

However, when I go to run any query on the Profile table, it will not work. Even a simple query such as

```
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
          ->select('p.*')
          ->from('Profile p');
        echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

fails.  I have tried changing the class name in the FROM to 'Profiles' instead of 'Profile'.  Still nothing.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: hmm... can't reproduce your error. what kind of error are you getting? I assume you're using mysql. have you tried a less verbose schema definition, i.e: don't define the ids for your models and only define the foreignAlias for your relations. shouldn't matter, but worth a go.

Comment: The thrown error would be usefull. Is there any custom code in the ´Base` models (or somewhere else) that might get called?

Comment: @Darragh: yes, am using mysql.  Have tried various schemas.  I usually am much less verbose in my definition, however, given that I was tearing my hair out I tried spelling things out fully in the schema.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @DrColossos: there is no custom code in the 'Base' models.  I am using Doctrine in the context of the CodeIgniter framework. However, I have had models running in CI/Doctrine in the past - so I was thinking it would be more my model rather than CI causing the problem (especially given that I can call simple queries on Identity and Profiletype).

Comment: That's wirded, I use Doctrine with Codeiginiter myself but never had a problem. Have you examinded the created tables in the database if they are correctly setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing every possible variable and tracing through my model line-by-line, I came to an embarrassing discovery:

The controller I was calling the Doctrine Query from was called profile.php.

**profile.php**

```
<?php
class Profile extends Controller {

    function Profile()     {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()     {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Profile');
        echo $q->getSqlQuery();
    }

}
```

Ass soon as I named the controller something else other than 'profile', it all suddenly worked.  Eg, naming it to docile.php:

**docile.php**

```
<?php
class Docile extends Controller {

    function Docile()     {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()     {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Profile');
        echo $q->getSqlQuery();
    }

}
```

'Profile' does not appear to be a reserved word in CodeIgniter ([link text](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html)).  It does appear, however, that you cannot call a doctrine 'table class' from a controller class of the same name.

Thanks for your input guys.  Hope this saves someone else similar hassles.